# How to show non modal window/alert in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, alert, non-modal

I want to display some data while the script is running by inserting some 'alert' to pop up during process. For example i'm modifying a google sheet, reset range of cells, unmerge and merge, set Validation etc. and i put some alert on any specific task to monitor.

I don't want to use getUi().alert() because i don't want to interact with the dialog box. I need non modal dialog without user interaction. I want the script to keep running  and keep show some pop up until the script is done. I can use Logger but i just want to experience in realtime what the script doing right now and which part that makes process so slow etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[toast(msg)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModeLessDialog()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#showModelessDialog(Object,String))